# Time Machine Backup Failed

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine, backup

Ive been using my Time Machine for almost 3 years without any problems. It's a 3 TB LaCie. This week it has decided to stop backing up my work. I tried repairing the disk and unmounting and remounting the disk a number of times but it's not working. After remounting the disk, it runs for about 10 minutes and then stops. Each time I then try to manually run a backup it immediately gives me an error message. The initial message I get is *"Time Machine couldn't back up to 'LaCie'"*. When I click on the details it tells me that an error occurred whilst creating the 'backup folder'. It has suggested that I verify and repair the disk, but I have done this to no avail.

I'm currently still running Mavericks on my Mac.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I should also note that I have 155 GB free on the disk so its not an error caused by a full disk

Comment: I tried a few things but then the disk stopped responding completely. It's been running constantly for the past 3 years so it looks like it's reached the end of its life. I've now got a new disk and a paperweight/door stop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had an issue with backups not completing and I solved it by deleting the partially created backup folder.

First turn time machine off (System Preferences > Time Machine > Off)

Navigate to `/Volumes/VOLUMENAME/Backups.backupdb/COMPUTERNAME/`, where you will see a list of folders dated by when the backup was created. If you see a folder with `.inProgress` in the name, move it to the trash.

Turn time machine back on and complete a backup. If it fails again, I'd recommend taking a look at the resources here: http://pondini.org/TM/C10.html

Comment: I tried deleting the '.inProgress' folder and it kept saying I didn't have the required permissions. However, I didn't do this with my time machine turned off. I will try this.

Comment: If you cannot delete it, select it in Finder, press command+i, and click the padlock in the lower-left-hand corner, and check "Ignore permissions on this volume"

Comment: @EzekielElin AFAIK the padlock has always been in the lower _right_ hand corner... Where did you see "Ignore permissions"? I'm running macOS Sierra.

Comment: @Arc676 Ignore permissions only shows up on volumes, and I don't know why I said left hand, sorry.

Comment: have you tried: sudo rm -r directory_name.   Be careful using rm -r, it could erase your whole disk.  Be sure the directory name is the directory you want to delete.

Comment: Update: If you're unable to delete this folder, you'll need to disable Time Machine first. On the new macOS, you can turn Time Machine off by going to System Preferences > Time Machine > Select Disk > Click on the Drive you're using > then click on Remove Drive.

Comment: This is bad advice IMO, as multiple users have complained that trashing the inProgress folder results in breaking the TM backup.

Comment: @At0mic Based on my understanding of the file system, if your backup is already broken this won't do anything to erase your existing files (which can be accessed through Finder)

Answer (score 1):

High Sierra:

I had the same problem description, and I was about to start looking at the filesystem when it went away. I would hypothesize that in High Sierra, there is some improved handling of the problem.

My details:

While checking my configuration, I had switched backup choices (before I was using the hard drive, I was using a remote volume for several years). When I switched back, and tried the hard drive again, it worked.