# How to restore inProgress files stuck in trash?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I have been unable to backup my MBP since June. After some Googling, I found this [link](https://osxdaily.com/2014/03/31/time-machine-stuck-preparing-backup-mac-fix/) that suggested I should trash my .inProgress files. However, I find that I am subsequently unable to empty my trash folder. I found this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286238/cant-remove-stalled-inprogress-time-machine-backup), which provided the correct way to delete .inProgress files. However, I cannot use `tmutil`, because I get this error:

> Invalid deletion target: (error 22)

This seems to be because the .inProgress files are now in `.Trashes`, and `tmutil` needs the files to be in a backup directory at least. Now I am trying to put the .inProgress files back into the Backup folder so I can use `tmutil` to delete them. However, when I try to put them back, I get this error:

> This operation can't be completed because backup items can't be modified.

How do I go about deleting the .inProgress files without risking damaging my existing backups?

Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if this will work but I'd try moving the inProgress file back to your machine's backup folder, then try tmutil. You might need to use single-user mode or another computer to bypass TM's write restrictions.

Comment: I wrote the original post you're referencing! My recommendation is to use the recovery mode system. Restart your computer into recovery mode and use disk utility to ensure your disk is mounted. Then, open up the Terminal utility and `cd` into `/Volumes` and find your disk. From here, `cd` into `.Trashes` and you should be able to `rm` stuff.

Comment: > I wrote the original post you're referencing!

Wow, I am not worthy. Thanks @EzekielElin! Just to make sure, in the second thread I linked, @theklaus says  that using `rm` will mess with the previous backups. Is this going to be a problem with the .inProgress files?

Comment: It shouldn't interfere with the files on the disk, but I can't guarantee that it won't mess smoething up with the ability to add new backups - however if those are already broken...